# Can't load WASM in a Vue component

Tags: vue.js, webpack, error-handling, emscripten, webassembly

In `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <emscripten.h>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
extern "C" {
    const char *testFunc(const char *parameter) {
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

Compilation command:

```bsh
em++ .\main.cpp -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["ccall", "cwrap"]' -o wasm_module.js;
```

In the Vue component:

```js
import wasmModule from "./wasm/wasm_module.js"; // I put both WASM and JS wrapper in the same folder

export default {
  created() {
    console.log(wasmModule);
  }
};
```

In `vue.config.js`, I've added:

```js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.wasm$/,
          loaders: ["wasm-loader"]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
```

But, I'm getting:

```
Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: abort(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0) at Error
```

---

### UPDATE

I ended using a slightly different compilation command, which was given by a member of the official [WebAssembly Discord server](https://discord.gg/hbeh5mt):

```
em++ .\main.cpp -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS'["call", "cwrap"]' -s MODULARIZE -s ENVIRONMENT="web" -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["_testFunc"]' -o wasm_module.js
```

Then, I dug up in the `wasm_module.js` and found a variable `scriptDirectory`, which is responsible for locating the `wasm_module.wasm` file
After logging it to the console, it outputted:

```
http://localhost:8080/js/
```

So, I moved the `.wasm` file into `public/js`, and by the way, deleted the `configureWebpack` entry as it's now useless

Now, I could:

```js
import wasmModule from "./wasm/wasm_module.js";
export default {
  async created() {
    const instance = await wasmModule();
    const func = instance._testFunc();
  }
};
```

However, there is still one problem:
No matter the arguments I pass into `_testFunc`, I'm getting the output `0` every single time

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was pretty simple

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <string>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
extern "C" {
  std::string* testFunc(std::string* parameter) {
    return parameter;
  }
}
```

Compilation:

```bsh
em++ .\main.cpp -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["ccall", "cwrap"]' -s MODULARIZE -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["_testFunc"]' -o wasm_module.js
```

The `wasm_module.js` should be somewhere under `src/`
The `wasm_module.wasm` should be under `public/js/`

Then, the Vue component:

```js
import moduleWasm from "./path/to/wasm_module.js";

export default {
  async created() {
    const instance = await moduleWasm();
    const func = instance.cwrap("testFunc", "string", ["string"]); // Note that: (func_name, return_type, [parameter_types])
    console.log(func("Hello World") === "Hello World"); // true
  }
};
```